# Providing power to NodeMCU (ESP8266) from the 5 V output of an Arduino

Tags: arduino, power, wifi, nodemcu, iot

Is it possible to power a NodeMCU from the 5 V output of an Arduino UNO board? I was trying to use the Vin of the NodeMCU as the input from the 5 V port of the Arduino, but didn't work.

Could anybody please provide me any suggestion on this matter. I want to do a project on the NodeMCU and I need to power it using a microcontroller, preferrably the mentioned one.

Comment: Why are you using an Arduino Uno AND a NodeMCU?  The 32-bit 80MHz NodeMCU is way more powerful than an UNO.   Why not just use the NodeMCU?

Comment: Yes it is possible and it ‘should’ work. How did you connect it up? I second Mr GT’s comments - why nodemcu and Uno? Arduino tools support the esp8266. Just about anything that can be done with a esp8266 has been done and put on the interwebs.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the UNO R3 board uses the MC33269D-5.0 chip, which is output current limited to around 800mA. This could be a factor into why the NodeMCU doesn't work, if it needs this or more current. The UNO R3 board (AVR, LEDs, misc.) will take a little of that current, so say this leaves 700mA for the NodeMCU board. My guess is this isn't enough current.

This is similar to plugging a Raspberry Pi board into a very cheap (1A or less) charger adapter and seeing it fail to boot.

Suggest you add a big fat capacitor to the 5V Output pin on the UNO R3 board, that will help with surge current demand and may fix your issue. I recommend a 100uF (10-25V) electrolytic.